# How to process this list of oddly structured strings with emoji flags into a dictionary?

Tags: python, string, text-processing

Imagine we have a list of strings with defined structure.
What would be the simplest strategy to parse such a list to get a dictionary?

```
mylist = [
    'Zynex 0,6',
    'PayPal 11',
    'PetIQ 0,5',
    'First Solar 0,7',
    'Upwork 1%',
    'NV5 Global 0,8',
    'TPI Composites 1',
    'Fiserv 0,5',
]
```

And I'm looking to get the result:

```
{
    'Zynex': 0.6,
    'PayPal': 11.0,
    'PetIQ': 0.5,
    'First Solar': 0.7,
    'Upwork': 1.0,
    'NV5 Global': 0.8,
    'TPI Composites': 1.0,
    'Fiserv': 0.5,
}
```

Comment: You need to know the character encoding of your input.

Comment: Also, use rsplit to pull off the last field an leave the rest as your string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually quite simple:

```
import re

mylist = [
    'Zynex 0,6',
    'PayPal 11',
    'PetIQ 0,5',
    'First Solar 0,7',
    'Upwork 1%',
    'NV5 Global 0,8',
    'TPI Composites 1',
    'Fiserv 0,5',
]

res = {}
for elem in mylist:
    key, val = re.sub(r"[^A-Za-z0-9, ]", "", elem).rsplit(" ", 1)
    res[key] = float(val.replace(",", "."))
 
print(res)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> {'Zynex': 0.6, 'PayPal': 11.0, 'PetIQ': 0.5, 'First Solar': 0.7, 'Upwork': 1.0, 'NV5 Global': 0.8, 'TPI Composites': 1.0, 'Fiserv': 0.5}
> ```

**Edit**:
Base on your comments, you also want to get a textual representation of the flag emojis. A crude solution is something like this:

```
def flag_to_str(emoji):
    return "".join(chr(c - 101) for c in emoji.encode()[3::4])


print(flag_to_str(""))  # US
print(flag_to_str(""))  # FI

# How it works:
print("".encode())  # b'\xf0\x9f\x87\xba\xf0\x9f\x87\xb8'
print("".encode()[3::4])  # b'\xba\xb8'
print("".encode()[3::4][0])  # 186
print(chr("".encode()[3::4][0] - 101))  # U
```

Explanation:
Most of the flag emojis are encoded as a sequence of two [regional indicator symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_indicator_symbol). E.g.  is + , and in hexadecimal that is represented as `f0 9f 87 ba f0 9f 87 b8` ([https://onlineutf8tools.com/convert-utf8-to-hexadecimal?input=&prefix=false&padding=false&spacing=true](https://onlineutf8tools.com/convert-utf8-to-hexadecimal?input=%F0%9F%87%BA%F0%9F%87%B8&prefix=false&padding=false&spacing=true)). From there we can see that each regional symbol starts with `f0 9f 87`, and the fourth byte is the amount 101₁₀ added to the equivalent ASCII uppercase character: https://www.asciitable.com. Thus 0xba <=> 186₁₀ - 101₁₀ = `U`.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the structure includes the numerical portion with no spaces as the last component of the string and that you want to strip 'us' from the leading component of the string.

The basic process you want is to iterate over the original list, doing the following on each pass:

1. separate the string into the key and value parts.
2. clean the value of unwanted stuff.
3. clean the key of unwanted stuff.
4. add the key:value pair to a dicitonary.

Something like this, but I didn't work on the value that has a percent:

```
my_list = ['Zynex 0,6',
 'PayPal 11',
 'PetIQ 0,5',
 'First Solar 0,7',
 #'Upwork 1%',
 'NV5 Global 0,8',
 'TPI Composites 1',
 'Fiserv 0,5']

##strip the 'us'
my_list = [x[2:] for x in my_list]
print(my_list[0].lstrip('us'))
##create a dictionary
my_dict = {}

## Now iterate over my_list and add key,value pairs to my_dict.
for e in my_list:
   ## make a list of the string, split on whitespace
   e = e.split()
   ## get the final element as value
   value = e[-1]
   ## replace commas with periods in value
   ## and convert to a float.
   value = float(value.replace(',','.'))
   ##join the rest of e into the key part.
   key = ' '.join(e[:-1])
   my_dict[key] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope this code help you:

```
mylist = ['Zynex 0,6',
 'PayPal 11',
 'PetIQ 0,5',
 'First Solar 0,7',
 'Upwork 1%',
 'NV5 Global 0,8',
 'TPI Composites 1',
 'Fiserv 0,5']

edited = []
dicto = {}
for val in mylist:
     new_val = val[2:]
     edited.append(new_val)
for i, val in enumerate(edited):
    tmp = val.rsplit(' ', 1)
    dicto[tmp[0]] = tmp[1]
print(dicto)
```